# Does Discrete Wavelet Consider Sampling Frequency or Cutoff Frequency of Bandpass Filter?

Tags: python, wavelet

I have EEG signal with a sampling frequency of `128 Hz`, and filtered from `1-30 Hz` using a bandpass filter. Now I want to know while decomposing the signal; does `DWT` decomposes it based on sampling frequency or cutoff frequency? Detailed Coefficients one should be `7.5-30` (if consider cutoff frequency), or `32-64` (if consider sampling frequency).

If we consider the cutoff frequency, we now that upper limit is a bit higher than `30`, so how can we correctly justify it?

I am using python [pywavelets](https://pywavelets.readthedocs.io/en/latest/index.html) and want to compute the frequency range of decomposed level.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

THe DWT does not really know about the actual sampling. It do cares about the relative frequency span. And it has not knowledge about pre-processing, like linear filtering.

So in your case, the detail coefficients of the first level of wavelet coefficients correspond,  more or less, to the `[128/2-128]/2` frequency range.

Because of the initial `[0-30]` low-pass filter, the above `[32-64]` first wavelet subband range is likely to contain little useful information.